# How can I wrap a data inside a cell?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable, html-table

This is a project in asp mvc 4
I'm trying to retrieve data from my database to be displayed on my table but it wont break the word and consumes the whole row sample image:

http://animobile.info/upload/1/wontwrap.JPG

I've already tried this code:

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="myExchangeRateTable" width="100">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Backup_Location) &thinsp; &thinsp;
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Backup_taken)
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Restore_Database_Name)
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date_Restored)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tbody align="left">
                    <tr>

                        <td style="word-wrap: break-word">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Backup_Location)
                        </td>
                        <td>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Backup_taken)</td>
                        <td>   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Restore_Database_Name)</td>
                        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date_Restored)</td>




                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            }

        </table>
```

Please help thank you so much!

Comment: you need to give appropriate widths to columns in percentage

Comment: Im sorry sir @EhsanSajjad here is the complete code

Comment: try using `word-break: break-all;`

Comment: Sir @Rohith it worked but it also break the table headers pls see the link to the image: http://animobile.info/upload/1/break.JPG

Comment: there are only two th(columns) in header, but five td(columns) in body. this is not a correct structure. you need equal amount of columns in body and header. otherwise merge cells

Comment: and also keep tbody outside of for loop, only tr needs to repeat.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.@MaulikAnand It was a very noob mistake. Im sorry I'm still a novice programmer! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/598wu/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
In your Gridmvc.css comment this /*white-space: nowrap;*/ and  /*min-height: 22px;*/

just like that :

```
table.grid-table td
{
    margin: 2px 6px 2px 6px; 
    padding: 1px 6px 1px 6px;
    /*min-height: 22px;*/
}
table.grid-table tr:nth-child(odd) td
{
    background: #e3fdf2;
    border: 1px solid #ADA7A7;
    /*white-space: nowrap;*/
}

table.grid-table tr:nth-child(even) td
{
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #ADA7A7;
    /*white-space: nowrap;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the width for each column specifically or just make it in percentage and you should specify a container so that the contents are not crossing the specified width.